# Error with tabular* (Underfull \hbox (badness 10000))

Tags: tables, debugging, badness

I get an error when compiling a tabular* environment.

The error I get is:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in alignment at lines 3--5
[]

Overfull \hbox (17.62482pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 3--6
[][]
```

I was able to isolate it to the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l}
2\\
\end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

Anyone can help on this?

Comment: you have specified that the table be stretched but given no way to stretch it, you need `\extracolsep{\fill}` but with only one column there really isn't anywhere useful that can stretch.

Comment: Cheers thanks. Solved.

Answer (score 2):

You have specified that the table be stretched but given no way to stretch it, you need `\extracolsep{\fill}` but with only one column there really isn't anywhere useful that can stretch.